# Creating new rows when specific terms within complex strings are recognised

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing strings with various formats (words, cases, special characters, spaces, hyphen, overlapping words). These were selected by surveyors from a pre-defined list. But the surveyor could select multiple terms for each row. **What I would like to do is recognise where these pre-defined terms occur and place them on a new row and duplicate all other columns**. Some example data where the pre-defined terms are different pressures:

```
Pre_defined_pressures <- c("Urbanisation", "Land cover (general)", "Agriculture / Horticulture", "Water Quality", "General-effects")
Surveyor_df <- as.data.frame(c("A","B","C","D"))
colnames(Surveyor_df ) <- "ID"
Surveyor_df$Year <- c(1999,1999,2000,2000)
Surveyor_df$Pressure <- c("Urbanisation Land cover (general)", 
                      "Urbanisation Land cover (general) Agriculture / Horticulture General-effects",
                      "Urbanisation Land cover (general) Water Quality General-effects", 
                      "Urbanisation Land cover (general) Agriculture / Horticulture Water Quality General-effects")
```

How the correct data frame should look.

```
Correct_df <- as.data.frame(c("A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D"))
colnames(Correct_df ) <- "ID"
Correct_df$Year <- c(1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000)
Correct_df$Pressure <- c("Urbanisation","Land cover (general)",
                     "Urbanisation","Land cover (general)","Agriculture / Horticulture","General-effects",
                     "Urbanisation", "Land cover (general)", "Water Quality", "General-effects",
                     "Urbanisation", "Land cover (general)", "Agriculture / Horticulture", "Water Quality","General-effects")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way in *base* might be to find the matches using `grepl` and then expand the Surveyor_df using `col` and the Pre_defined_pressures using `row`.

```
. <- t(sapply(Pre_defined_pressures, grepl, Surveyor_df$Pressure, fixed=TRUE))
. <- cbind(Surveyor_df[col(.)[.], 1:2], Pressure = Pre_defined_pressures[row(.)[.]])
all.equal(., Correct_df, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
.
#    ID Year                   Pressure
#1    A 1999               Urbanisation
#1.1  A 1999       Land cover (general)
#2    B 1999               Urbanisation
#2.1  B 1999       Land cover (general)
#2.2  B 1999 Agriculture / Horticulture
#2.3  B 1999            General-effects
#3    C 2000               Urbanisation
#3.1  C 2000       Land cover (general)
#3.2  C 2000              Water Quality
#3.3  C 2000            General-effects
#4    D 2000               Urbanisation
#4.1  D 2000       Land cover (general)
#4.2  D 2000 Agriculture / Horticulture
#4.3  D 2000              Water Quality
#4.4  D 2000            General-effects
```

Comment: Thank you. Does 1:2 represent the column numbers that require duplication? I.e. if there were 2 columns the other side of 'Pressure', would it be 'c(1,2,4,5)'?

Comment: Yes here `1:2` selects column 1 and 2 of Surveyor_df. Instead of `c(1,2,4,5)` also `-3` could be written, to get all but not column 3.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is extracting each possible value into a separate column and then pivotting longer. This would be easier if the values were separated by a unique character, but in your data a space can either be a lexical space or a separator.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

Surveyor_df |> 
  mutate(urb = str_extract(Pressure, "Urbanisation"),
         lan = str_extract(Pressure, "Land cover \\(general\\)"),
         agr = str_extract(Pressure, "Agriculture / Horticulture"),
         wat = str_extract(Pressure, "Water Quality")
         ) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = urb:wat, values_to = "pressure") |> 
  select(-Pressure, -name) |> 
  filter(!is.na(pressure))
```

Output:

```r
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>    ID     Year pressure                  
#>    <chr> <dbl> <chr>                     
#>  1 A      1999 Urbanisation              
#>  2 A      1999 Land cover (general)      
#>  3 B      1999 Urbanisation              
#>  4 B      1999 Land cover (general)      
#>  5 B      1999 Agriculture / Horticulture
#>  6 C      2000 Urbanisation              
#>  7 C      2000 Land cover (general)      
#>  8 C      2000 Water Quality             
#>  9 D      2000 Urbanisation              
#> 10 D      2000 Land cover (general)      
#> 11 D      2000 Agriculture / Horticulture
#> 12 D      2000 Water Quality
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I would ideally like something that picks up the pre-defined terms automatically though as there are lots of them in my full dataset and have varied structures that I would not know how to code (e.g. the back slashes next to land cover (general)). Also note a couple of question edits to better reflect a bit more complexity I'm experiencing in my dataset. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Define a named vector with comma as a separator mark (could be any symbol). Replace existing `Pressure` values, and remove trailing comma, then create separate rows for each instance using `tidy::separate_rows`. Then some tidying up of text.

This method avoids manually typing out values, which may be a pain if you have a lot of different values for `Pressure`.

Updated following OP's comment and revised input dataset.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)



vec_p <- paste0(Pre_defined_pressures, ",")

names(vec_p) <-   Pre_defined_pressures

Correct_df <- 
  Surveyor_df %>% 
  mutate(Pressure = str_replace_all(Pressure, coll(vec_p)),
         Pressure = str_remove(Pressure, ",$")) %>% 
  separate_rows(Pressure, sep = ",") %>% 
  mutate(Pressure = str_squish(Pressure))

Correct_df
#> # A tibble: 15 × 3
#>    ID     Year Pressure                  
#>    <chr> <dbl> <chr>                     
#>  1 A      1999 Urbanisation              
#>  2 A      1999 Land cover (general)      
#>  3 B      1999 Urbanisation              
#>  4 B      1999 Land cover (general)      
#>  5 B      1999 Agriculture / Horticulture
#>  6 B      1999 General-effects           
#>  7 C      2000 Urbanisation              
#>  8 C      2000 Land cover (general)      
#>  9 C      2000 Water Quality             
#> 10 C      2000 General-effects           
#> 11 D      2000 Urbanisation              
#> 12 D      2000 Land cover (general)      
#> 13 D      2000 Agriculture / Horticulture
#> 14 D      2000 Water Quality             
#> 15 D      2000 General-effects
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I like that. Why are some values not split, e.g., `Land cover (general) Agriculture / Horticulture` and `Land cover (general) Agriculture / Horticulture`?

Comment: Thank you for this. I've updated the question slightly as your code didn't quite fit my full dataset. I think this could be the effect of an overlapping word between the pre-defined terms? Or the inclusion of a hyphen?

Comment: @Andrea M and @James White Opps, I didn't spot that - something to do with the way `str_replace_all` matches text I think. This can be corrected by wrapping the replacement vector in `coll()` according to the documentation: "Compare strings respecting standard collation rules." Can't say I fully understand this but it seems to end up with the desired output!